who was ruling saurashtra at the time of ramayana
There is this verse from valmiki ramayan which says

प्राचीनान्सिन्धु सौवीरान्सौराष्ट्रेयांश्च पार्थिवान्। दाक्षिणात्यान्नरेन्द्रांश्च समस्तानानयस्व ह।

There is not much information available on internet regarding who was ruling saurashtra and sindhu desh at the time of ramayan.
